# Suppressing info status logs in Spring logback

Tags: xml, spring, logging, logback

Status logs are being written to FileAppender.
I have tried with `debug="false" 
I have also tried with

```
<statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />
```

Do you know how to suppress INFO status logs into FileAppender?

This is my logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<appender name="consoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader>
        <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/ANALYTICS.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover. Make sure the path matches the one in the file element or else
         the rollover logs are placed in the working directory. -->
        <fileNamePattern>logs/ANALYTICS_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader>
        <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>

</appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    </root>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
```

Comment: have you setup slf4j/logback correctly? Spring is using commons logging by default so it might not be listening to your logback.xml